# Forge viewer with Potree point cloud big memory leak

Tags: autodesk-forge

I have a question regarding the Potree point cloud method I use from online sample.
We have a Potree model with size 6GB and sometimes more up to 100GB, and when showing that in Forge, the memory keeps growing up until the viewer crashes, is there anything we can do to fix this?

Comment: I want even you ask if there is a way I can apply this to the Forge sample.
https://github.com/potree/potree/issues/628

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can limit the number of points for Potree to keep in memory at any point in time:

```js
Potree.Global.pointLoadLimit = 1000 * 1000; // limit the number of points to 1 million
```

It looks like the default value is [10,000,000,000](https://github.com/petrbroz/forge-potree-demo/blob/master/public/scripts/potree/potree.js#L328).